# TYPO3 11: Redirect to www-version and keep path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, typo3

I have set up a TYPO3 11 website with the main domain `https://www.my.website.de/`
Now I want to redirect requests to the non www-version of the website to the www-version.
Example: my.website.de/subpage should redirect to `www.my.website.de/subpage`

In htaccess I have defined the following rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.my.website\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But the redirect does not respect the path.
When I enter the url my.website.de/subpage it gets redirected to `www.my.website.de/index.php` and not to  `www.my.website.de/subpage`

How can I define the redirect to respect the path as well?

Comment: Most likely this is an issue with the order of rules. So that the redirection to `/index.php` is applied _first_ by your rules and _then_ the redirection to the other host name. In general you have to keep in mind that rewriting rules are applied in the order they are implemented in the your various configuration files. But the redirection to the other host (to add the "www." prefix") earlier (so further up) in your files. Such rules typically come _first_ , before any rewriting rules for the application router.

Comment: Thank you. That was the crucial hint. I set the rules at the start of the htaccess-file and now the redirection works.

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help. Have fun!